Do any full-node clients compress blocks?
Does Bitcoin Core or any other full node capable client compress the blocks in transit on the network or locally on the node's filesystem?
I used 7z to compress a handful of my locally stored blocks, and I got 50% compression!

not that I know, but this would be a good side project to do

No compression is currently used. See this answer with more references.

I dont think they compress blocks or transaction data in any way, I used Utreexod full node, they sent the whole blocks in raw form and it was saved as it is on my local machine, just in a different file format.
